# Pass eloquent collection to array

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

```
$task = Task::all();
$sort = $task->sortByDesc('id')->toArray();

return view('welcome')->with('sort',$sort);
```

I want to pass Eloquent collection object to an array and then sort to iterate through but I get this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I don't know what the error means?

Comment: how you used the sort variable in view it would be helpful if you show the view file code too

Comment: Please can you add the foreach loop you are iterating on view file

Comment: Or you can try to dump your sort variable to check if any element is having array instead of string

Comment: @foreach($sort as $s)
    <li>{{$s}}</li>
    @endforeach

Comment: I dump variable and i got array

Comment: you cant do {{ $s }} since its actually and model object which has been converted into an array so you can need to grab the column instead of printing the whole array like {{ $s['name'] }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// controller
$task = Task::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
return view('welcome')->with('task',$task);

// view
@foreach($task as $t)
{{$t->colunm_name}}
@endforeach
```

Laravel get() returns an array of object